# PyCharm не видит модуль pastebin

Tags: python, python-3.x

Модуль pastebin

ipython3 модуль импортирует:[image: ipython3]

PyCharm говорит, что такого модуля нет:[image: PyCharm]

Ставил по инструкции со страницы загрузки, т.е. скачал архив, распаковал, перешел в папку и выполнил: `python setup.py install`

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже это старый баг себя проявляет: https://github.com/Morrolan/PastebinAPI/issues/1

Попробуй откатиться на предыдущую версию: 1.1.0. У меня заработало после этого.

К слову через pip все нормально устанавливается:

```
pip install pastebin==1.1.0
```